# jQuery carousel - any number of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I have a Flickity carousel of images that, when you click an image/slide, opens a modal window to show a zoomed in version of said image. Within that modal I have a left and right buttons to scroll through all zoomed in images.

My problem is my code breaks if I have any more or less than 3 images in the slider. I need to convert it so that it will not break no matter how many images I have, whether its 1, 4, 2 or 8 etc. How do I do this?

My JS below has been reduced to show just the relevant bits. I also have a function for a right button too. See jsFiddle for current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/293sh54n/6/

**JS**

```
var activeDivimg;
$( ".product--slider .slide" ).each(function( index ) {
  // Show the modal window
  $('#product-slider-flickity img').click(function(){
    activeDivimg = parseInt($(this).parent().index());
    console.log(activeDivimg)
    $("#imageshow").html('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"/>');
    $(".p-image-zoom").addClass("md-show");
  });
});
// Zoomed in controls - Scroll left button
$('.left').click(function(){
   if(activeDivimg < 1 ){
    activeDivimg = 2
   }else{
      console.log('kundi'+activeDivimg)
      activeDivimg = activeDivimg - 1
   }
   console.log('left'+activeDivimg)
   $("#imageshow").html('<img src="'+$('.slide').eq(activeDivimg).find('img').attr('src')+'"/>');
    console.log(activeDivimg+"asd")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should get images count. After this in left click you use activeDivimg = imagesCount - 1; instead of activeDivimg = 2; Same thing right click.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/293sh54n/10/)

```
var imageCount = $('.slide').length;
var activeDivimg;
$( ".product--slider .slide" ).each(function( index ) {
  // Show the modal window
  $('#product-slider-flickity img').click(function(){
    activeDivimg = parseInt($(this).parent().index());
    console.log(activeDivimg)
    $("#imageshow").html('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"/>');
    $(".p-image-zoom").addClass("md-show");
  });
});
// Zoomed in controls - Scroll left button
$('.left').click(function(){
   if(activeDivimg < 1 ){
    activeDivimg = imagesCount - 1;
   }else{
      console.log('kundi'+activeDivimg)
      activeDivimg = activeDivimg - 1
   }
   console.log('left'+activeDivimg)
   $("#imageshow").html('<img src="'+$('.slide').eq(activeDivimg).find('img').attr('src')+'"/>');
    console.log(activeDivimg+"asd")
});
```

Comment: This looks great and I've tested it out with multiple images and works great, however, there is a tiny issue. In the modal window, between the last and first image (so when you loop from finish to start) you see an image not found error as a new slide. I guess this is because the JS is trying to find an image that doesn't exist. Does that make sense? Would you be able to fix and I'll accept the answer?

Comment: Because if there is 5 images, imagesCount must be 4.  The line must be like this activeDivimg = imagesCount -1; Last index of array is not array length. My fault sorry